# How to setup table per type inhertiance in entity framework when the derived table uses its own primary key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, table-per-type

Suppose I have a table structure such as:

```
Order    
  ID int, primary key 
  Name, string
  OtherOrderFields...

RetailOrder
  ID int, primary key
  OrderID, foreign key
  RetailOrderFields...
```

In entity framework 4, is it possible to set up table per type inheritance so that RetailOrder derives from Order?  All the examples I've seen so far have the derived class using the foreign key (OrderID in this example) as the primary key for the table, but what if that's not the case and each table maintains its own primary key?

Comment: based on your design you treating each tables as a separate table in order to derive you need to have some sort of connection between them

Comment: There is a connection, OrderID of RetailOrder is coming from the ID field of the Order table - it's a foreign key, thus implying a strong relationship.

Comment: you can also create a relation table like orderRetailOrder and avoid foreighn key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's impossible. I think, your database schema guess aggregation (1-1 relation) instead of inheritance.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'guess aggregation', but I'm satisified that the answer is 'no'